# How to generate a sample xml from a class file

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating a model in c# and the idea is that later the app I am doing will read data from xml and convert it to object, however I would like to generate a sample xml of that. how can I do that?

my sample c# class is:

```
 public class SiteDefinition
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public List<MasterPage> MasterPages { get; set; }
        public List<File> Files { get; set; }
        public List<PageLayout> PageLayouts { get; set; }
        public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
        public List<ContentType> ContentTypes { get; set; }
        public List<StyleSheet> StyleSheets { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the sample?  Are you looking to auto-generate dummy values for say `<Name>John Smith</Name>`?

Comment: yes, I want to generate a sample xml that resembles the c# class, something like <sitedefinition name="xx" version="1.0"><MasterPages><MasterPage/></MasterPages>

Comment: The least amount of investigation is to create a dummy instance with degenerate values and serialize it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var instance = new SiteDefinition();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SiteDefinition));

using(var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Path\\To\\File.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
}
```

And if you want to customize the output (attributes, etc) there are many attributes that you can decorate your class and class members with. Check out [this MSDN article for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx)

Comment: will this generate sample values?

Comment: No. You first have to populate `instance` with sample values.

Comment: no, it will just write whatever values are in the `instance` of your class. You can use a mocking framework to generate default values if you need to though. I usually use [nBuilder](https://code.google.com/p/nbuilder/) for that type of thing

Comment: Also, you'll have to decide on the XML format to use. The above will use the default format of the XML Serializer. You may want a different format.

Answer (score 1):

XML Serialization

Required Namespace

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Read and write class as XML

```
    public static List<SiteDefinition> Read()
    {
        XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SiteDefinition>));
        using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(Global.AppRoot, configFileName)))
        {
            return reader.Deserialize(file) as List<SiteDefinition>;
        }
    }

    public static void Write(List<SiteDefinition> settings)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SiteDefinition>));
        using (FileStream file = File.Create(Path.Combine(Global.AppRoot, configFileName)))
        {
            writer.Serialize(file, settings);
        }
    }
```